# I can't get python module for transip to work correctly

Tags: python, api, dns

I try to get a script to work for checking / editing my dns at transip. It works partly until I realy want to do something.

Current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from transip.service.domain import DomainService

basedomain='gemert.net'
key='MY_KEY_IS_SECRET'

dnsservice = DomainService('MY_USERNAME', private_key=key)
print(dnsservice.get_domain_names())
print(dnsservice.check_availability(basedomain))
print(dnsservice.get_info(basedomain))
```

The result when running is al follows:

```
./setdns.py 
[mydomain1.com, mydomain2.org, mydomain3.net]
inyouraccount
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setdns.py", line 49, in <module>
    print(dnsservice.get_info(basedomain))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suds/__init__.py", line 166, in <lambda>
    __str__ = lambda x: x.__unicode__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suds/sudsobject.py", line 172, in __unicode__
    return self.__printer__.tostr(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suds/sudsobject.py", line 256, in tostr
    return self.process(object, history, indent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suds/sudsobject.py", line 265, in process
    return self.print_object(object, h, n+2, nl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suds/sudsobject.py", line 312, in print_object
    s.append(self.process(item[1], h, n, True))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suds/sudsobject.py", line 273, in process
    return self.print_collection(object, h, n+2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suds/sudsobject.py", line 352, in print_collection
    s.append(self.process(item, h, n-2))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suds/sudsobject.py", line 265, in process
    return self.print_object(object, h, n+2, nl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/suds/sudsobject.py", line 282, in print_object
    if d in h:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transip/service/objects.py", line 57, in __eq__
    return self.name == other.name and self.type == other.type and self.content == other.content
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'
```

What am I doing wrong? The first 2 commands seem to work but the `dnsservice.get_info(basedomain)` isn't working

Version of *transip* module

```
pip3 show transip
Name: transip
Version: 2.0.0
Summary: TransIP API Connector
Home-page: https://github.com/benkonrath/transip-api
Author: Go About B.V.
Author-email: tech@goabout.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
Requires: cryptography, suds-jurko, requests
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, I don't know much about the transip api.

I took a look at their code where the error is being thrown in [transip/service/objects.py](https://github.com/benkonrath/transip-api/blob/master/transip/service/objects.py#L52), and it looks like they have a bug:

```py
def __eq__(self, other): 
    # other can be a list. This check ensures that other is a DnsEntry. 
    if not hasattr(self, 'name') or not hasattr(self, 'type') or not hasattr(self, 'content'): 
        return False 

    # expire is intentionally not used for equality. 
    return self.name == other.name and self.type == other.type and self.content == other.content
```

The comment says that `other` can be a list so they're ensuring that it's a DNSEntry, but they're actually not checking that at all. If `self` has the attributes `name`, `type`, and `content`, and `other` does not, this will break. In your case, `other` is a list so it doesn't have the `name` attribute.

Something like changing the first if statement to check `other` instead of `self` may solve it:

```py
if not hasattr(other, 'name') or not hasattr(other, 'type') or not hasattr(other, 'content'): 
        return False
```

It would actually probably be better to just check if `other` is a list:

```py
if isinstance(other, list):
   return False
```

If I were you, I'd either open an issue in transip API GitHub repo, or do a quick fix yourself and submit a pull request.